# Give a background curved corners

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm trying to make a website based similar to [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C2wf.png) I [found on Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/4929361-Meet-Me-Concept). I decided to incorporate the curved background, however I'm not sure how to implement this. I've tried to make a div with the full background with background-color: #04060F but I'm not entirely sure of how to do this nor get it to fill until a specific padding and border radius.

EDIT: I'm getting [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZs9I.png)

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean :

```
div{
    border-radius: 5px;//or any length
}
```

this will give you the rounded corners you're looking for.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Here is a very simple example :

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded">
  Some text
</div>
```

Comment: That works out however there's a triangle cutout in the center on the right and left (might be with my browser FF) and how can I get it to stretch to the whole page?

Comment: That is another question entirely. Investigate it, research it, test it multiple browsers, and if you still have a problem, then make brand new post.

Comment: I can't see the triangle you're mentionning.
If it is in your version of the code can you post a screenshot in the edits ?

Comment: @Nasta I've edited my question and uploaded my results

Comment: Looks like you have two blocks and trying to apply boreder-radius to all the corners.This works fine for the top and bottom, but where the two block meets you get that weird triangle you were talking about.
You can either round the top and bottom corners. You can also put all your elements into a larger <div> and apply the border radius to this <div>.

Comment: @Nasta how do I do this?

Comment: in css : 
    div{
        border-radius: 0px 1px 2px 3px 
    }
will set respectively the radius of top left, top right, bottom right and bottom left corners.
You can play around with this .
Also you should read that : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius .

Answer (score 0):

This is the main skeleton I was thinking of looking at the pic you posted.

```css
.main {
    background-color: red;
    }
.badge{
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    }
```

```html
<body class="main">
    <div class="badge">
        lorem<br>
        ipsum<br>
        dolor<br>
        sit<br>
        amen<br>
    </div>
</body>
```